# Airflow scheduler is exiting

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

While running DAG on Airflow, scheduler was exited with below exception. I wanted to understand possible reason for this.

DAG was successful in this case and seems like next DAG was not scheduled as Airflow ended up below issue

```
  [2023-04-06 12:51:53,853] {scheduler_job.py:753} ERROR - Exception when executing SchedulerJob._run_scheduler_loop
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/centos/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 736, in _execute
        self._run_scheduler_loop()
      File "/home/centos/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 824, in _run_scheduler_loop
        num_queued_tis = self._do_scheduling(session)
      File "/home/centos/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 898, in _do_scheduling
        self._start_queued_dagruns(session)
      File "/home/centos/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 1052, in _start_queued_dagruns
        DagRun.active_runs_of_dags((dr.dag_id for dr in dag_runs), only_running=True, session=session),
      File "/home/centos/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 68, in wrapper
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/centos/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dagrun.py", line 256, in active_runs_of_dags
        query = query.filter(cls.dag_id.in_(list(set(dag_ids))))
      File "/home/centos/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 1052, in <genexpr>
        DagRun.active_runs_of_dags((dr.dag_id for dr in dag_runs), only_running=True, session=session),
      File "/home/centos/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 376, in iterrows
        for row in self._fetchiter_impl():
      File "/home/centos/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 120, in chunks
        fetch = cursor._raw_all_rows()
      File "/home/centos/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 400, in _raw_all_rows
        return [make_row(row) for row in rows]
      File "/home/centos/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 400, in <listcomp>
        return [make_row(row) for row in rows]
      File "/home/centos/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py", line 1816, in process
        return loads(value)
    _pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated
    [2023-04-06 12:51:54,859] {process_utils.py:129} INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to group 27030. PIDs of all processes in the group: [27030]
    [2023-04-06 12:51:54,859] {process_utils.py:80} INFO - Sending the signal Signals.SIGTERM to group 27030
    [2023-04-06 12:51:54,991] {process_utils.py:75} INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=27030, status='terminated', exitcode=0, started='2023-01-31 20:44:27') (27030) terminated with exit code 0
    [2023-04-06 12:51:54,992] {scheduler_job.py:765} INFO - Exited execute loop`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, the error message is `_pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated`
it looks like that there is a memory/network/disk space issue.