# Airflow worker failed to launch

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-celery

We are running Airflow cluster with Celery executor. We had issue related to scheduler wrt pickle data issue([Airflow scheduler is exiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75950120/airflow-scheduler-is-exiting)) and we cleared/reset DB. Post this Airflow worker failing to start. Error below

```
raise self.mapping[code](*args, **kwargs)
werkzeug.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden: You don't have the permission to access the requested resource. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
```

**Config details**

We are running this Airflow with Redis/Elasticache broker

Auth backend is set to

```
auth_backends = airflow.api.auth.backend.session,airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth
```